# Liferay 7.4 GA27+: DLURLHelperUtil.getPreviewURL returning old legacy URL format for Document and Media images

Tags: liferay, liferay-7.4

In **Liferay 7.4 GA27** and above, I've noticed a change in the URL format for Document and Media images. Previously, the URL was generated as `[server-address]/documents/[site-id]/[folder-id]/[file-name]/[UUID]`, but now it is in the format `[server-address]/documents/d/[site's friendly url]/[file-friendly-URL]`.

I'm using the **DLURLHelperUtil** method **getPreviewURL** to obtain the image URL. However, it seems to be providing the old legacy URL format instead of the updated one.

What steps can I take to address this issue and ensure compatibility with Liferay 7.4 GA27+? Are there any new methods or changes in the API that I should be aware of? Any insights or workarounds from the community would be greatly appreciated.

I've checked the Liferay documentation for version 7.4 GA27 but didn't find specific information on this issue.
The community forums have been explored, but I couldn't find relevant discussions on this particular matter.
Any code examples or suggestions on manually constructing the URLs based on the new format would be helpful.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Have you tried the behavior of the latest release? GA releases are now at 100+, much might have been fixed since then. Also: Does the legacy URL work? Because if the system generate any _working_ URL, there's nothing to fix.

Comment: @OlafKock Yes, I am using GA 105. When uploading an image in Document and Media and checking the link, it shows the [server-address]/documents/d/[site's-friendly-url]/[file-friendly-url]. However, when using the `DLURLHelperUtil` method `getPreviewURL`, it returns the legacy URL, which does not map or match the URL displayed in Document and Media -> Image -> Information (i) icon -> Latest Version URL. The legacy URL does not work.